# Change UILabel Text via UIAlertAction

Tags: swift

I want to have an alert action change the text of a UILabel in my View. Code below:

```
@IBAction func statusChange(_ sender: UIButton){

        let playalert = UIAlertController(title: "OPERATION: \(sender.accessibilityIdentifier!) NOT POSSIBLE", message: "Convert op to PLAY mode to proceed", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let recordalert = UIAlertController(title: "OPERATION: \(sender.accessibilityIdentifier!) NOT POSSIBLE", message: "Convert op to STOP mode to proceed", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let statechangealert = UIAlertController(title: "OPERATION: \(sender.accessibilityIdentifier!) WILL NOW PROCEED", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)


        let stopAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Convert", style: .default, handler: { action in
                         self.statusDVR.text = "STOP"//"\(sender.accessibilityIdentifier!)"
                            })

        let continueAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: .default, handler: { action in
                        self.statusDVR.text = ""//"\(sender.accessibilityIdentifier!)"
                         })

        let returnAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Return", style: .default, handler: { action -> Void in

                            })

        playalert.addAction(stopAction)
        playalert.addAction(returnAction)
        recordalert.addAction(stopAction)
        recordalert.addAction(returnAction)
        statechangealert.addAction(continueAction)

        //record was tapped, check if DVR stopped first
        if (sender.tag == 5 && pwrStat == true ) {
            //if not stopped send alert
            if statusDVR.text !=  "STOP" {
              self.present(recordalert, animated:true, completion: nil)
                //if user tapped returned action
               if statusDVR.text != "STOP" {
                   self.present(statechangealert, animated:true, completion: nil)
               } else {
                    return
                }
            } else {
                statusDVR.text = "RECORD"
            }
```

The stopAction should convert a UILAbel called statusDVR in the view controller, but it doesn't do it.

I haven't tried implementing the other Actions yet, because I am stuck trying to figure out why my UILabel's text won't change. Thank you for any help :)

Comment: What's not working? Is the action's handler being called? Is the text just not updating? Have you tried dispatching the UI change onto the main thread?

Comment: So when I get the alert, I click my stopAction button on the alert, and the label statusDVR.text doesn't update to "STOP"

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in `DispatchQueue.main.async { }` and if you set a breakpoint is the handler getting called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this code makes no sense:

```
if statusDVR.text !=  "STOP" {
      self.present(recordalert, animated:true, completion: nil)
      if statusDVR.text != "STOP" {
           self.present(statechangealert, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

That code tries to present two alerts at the same time. That is illegal.

I think you think that when you say

```
self.present(recordalert, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

...your code magically comes to a stop while the user interacts with the alert and then proceeds after the user dismisses the alert. That’s not the case. Your code never magically stops; it just keeps right on going.

---

As for the actual question you asked about, the problem is simply that what you're doing is illegal:

```
    playalert.addAction(stopAction)
    playalert.addAction(returnAction)
    recordalert.addAction(stopAction)
    recordalert.addAction(returnAction)
```

No! You cannot take one UIAlertAction and somehow magically "share" it between two different UIAlertControllers. Every UIAlertController needs UIActions that belong to it alone. In other words, *do not call `addAction` on the same UIAlertAction twice.*

Just to demonstrate more simply, try running this code:

```
let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Test", style: .default) {
    _ in print("test")
}
let alert1 = UIAlertController(title: "Hello", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Hello2", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
alert1.addAction(action1)
alert2.addAction(action1)
self.present(alert1, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The alert appears, you tap the Test button, the alert disappears — but nothing prints in the console. Now comment out the next to last line:

```
// alert2.addAction(action1)
```

... and run the code again. This time, when you tap Test, "test" appears in the console.

Comment: So, its sloppy, imcomplete code: but essentially I want to throw an alert that warns user that it can't jump into a Mode unless it is in STOP mode first. stopAction is the  alert action is supposed to convert the mode to STOP and then on the 2nd alert (statechangealert) warns user that the state will change to the requested operation. (Requirements of the assignment) My issue right now is that, I can't even convert the UILabel to STOP mode with the stopAction

Comment: So I did try removing the 2nd conditional, and still no changes to the label.

Comment: Yes, because you're calling `addAction` on the same UIAlertAction multiple times. You can't do that. Added that to my answer.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Thank you so much for the clarification. Makes perfect sense now. 

Solution works great. Thank you for educating me on how to properly use alert actions :)

Comment: oh and just out of curiosity, could you tell me or link me to a reason why 2 alert controllers can't share the same actions? why is this is the case?

Comment: I don't know how to answer that, sorry. It seems so obviously ontologically impossible. "How can you be in two places at once when you're not anywhere at all?" (Sorry, that's an [obscure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_Can_You_Be_in_Two_Places_at_Once_When_You%27re_Not_Anywhere_at_All) joke.)

Comment: Haha I like that. Gonna have to pick up your book.

Comment: I've filed a bug report. Either this should work or the runtime should throw a wobbly when it sees you doing it. :) Leaving you confused by an inoperative alert action is not nice.